# Better way to save sqlite database file(.db) in ios application

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

What is better way to copy sqlite database file(.db) in ios application means that in NSBundle or in Document folder.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the file, you can keep it in your bundle no need to copy it to documents folder, if you need to modify you need to copy it to documents directory (because bundle is read-only). If you explain your intentions a little bit, we can help you more.

Comment: @Mithun Thanks, I want to read and write from database file.

Comment: I wrote [this post](http://myiostricks.blogspot.in/2013/07/another-great-day.html) some times before..may be this is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DB.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];

    if (success) return;

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KURANDB2.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```